# Angular UI Dialog - Closing and Reopening from Dialog causes Background

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to close and reopen a dialog from the actual dialog controller's view.  What ends up happening is that after  dialog close/open, it won't properly close again.  Escape works on some browsers (but the overlay remains) and clicking the background may cause the dialog to close but the overlay will remain (browser dependant).

Question:  How can I close/reopen a dialog from a function/button/event on the dialog's controller and that the dialog's close works properly (on escape or clicking background).

The demo below is just a boiled down sample that demonstrates the issue as I will be doing a next/prev and I'd like to close/open on those clicks but am having this issue with not being able to exit the modal.

Here is the online demo:  http://plnkr.co/h8djNiSlH6c7d8SNzMmb

1. Open dialog
2. Close dialog - works fine except IE (another issue).
3. Open dialog
4. Click button inside dialog to close/reopen
5. Try to close the dialog

Controllers:

```
function PopupCtrl($scope, $dialog, dialog, item, Utils) {

    $scope.items = Utils.getItems();
    $scope.item = item;
    $scope.reOpen = function (item) {
        item = $scope.items[1];
        dialog.close();
        var d = $dialog.dialog({
            dialogFade: true,
            backdropClick: true,
            dialogOpenClass: 'modal-open',
            resolve: {
                item: function () {
                    return angular.copy(item)
                }
            }
        });
        d.open('dialog.html', 'PopupCtrl');
    };
}

function MainCtrl($scope, $window, $dialog, $location, $timeout, Utils) {
    $scope.items = Utils.getItems();

    $scope.openDialog = function (item) {
        item = $scope.items[0];
        var d = $dialog.dialog({
            dialogFade: true,
            dialogOpenClass: 'modal-open',
            resolve: {
                item: function () {
                    return angular.copy(item)
                }
            }
        });
        d.open('dialog.html', 'PopupCtrl');

    };

}
```

I've tried this with angular bootstrap v0.2.0 and v.0.3.0 so it is either a bug or there is something I am missing with regards to how I am coding the logic.

Comment: That is some wild stuff. I assumed there was some scope conflict (like PopupCtrl going out of scope on dialog.close()), so I tried moving the dialog open code to a service and calling it after a setTimeout, but when I do that, no new dialog ever opens as if $dialog inside of PopupCtrl is tainted somehow after its closed.

Comment: Yeah, I just couldn't figure it out.   The animations look great in chrome and ie, but not so much in FF but that's just an aside

Comment: I ended up filing an issue and pull request on the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the core dialog directive.  Filed a issue and consequent pull request to address:

Details here:  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/381